# How do i Format a Date Column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel,  I am trying to Modify a Timestamp column 
My Record column has values like

```
'2016-05-12T14:56:20.407Z'
```

When i Right click and try to format the cell and select date,

it is not recognizing this as date. Any Pointers on what should i be doing ?

I Tried splitting the value by Date and Month - it throws error.

Comment: remove the T in the Middle and Z at the end and it will recognize it as a date.

Comment: Are the ' actually a part of the data or did you put those in for formatting purposes?

Comment: Thank you this helped.  a Little crude way but nevertheless worked.. Can you Reply in answer .. Will mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a cleaner way to do this, but to get both the date and the time into another cell in date/time format, you can use:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"Z"," ")) +TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"Z"," "))
```

This strips the `T` and `Z` from the string and then converts it to both date and time (Adding the two together).

@Sorceri got my brain working. Since your dates and times are nicely padded with 0s so every piece of the date/time is in the same place, you could use `left()` and `mid()` to pick out the pieces:

```
=LEFT(A1,10) + MID(A1, 12, 12)
```

This is similar to the above, just without all the substituting and whatnot. It gets the date portion of the string and adds it to the time portion of the string. When you add those two substrings together excel detects that it's date and time respectively, converts it, adds them together and spits out an excel friendly date/time that you can format.

Comment: Looks like the format is yyyy-mm-dd so this would also work:  =DATEVALUE(REPLACE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),11,1," "))  where A1 is the cell with the date text

Comment: I was thinking that `LEFT() + Mid()` would work nicely too. Might be less ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Text to columns to split the data. Use the "T" as the delimiter and you will see one column with date values. To turn the time part into time values, run a Find/Replace and replace "Z" with nothing.